# Cannot start the driver service on localhost when using geckodriver with Firefox 50.0.1 in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I'm learning Selenium from the scratch and trying to run a test case on Firefox 50.0.1 using `geckodriver` I installed in VS2015 by selecting `Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64`

However, when running the test I got an exception

> Cannot start the driver service on localhost

What am I missing?
I was following some tutorials and performed step by step walk-through.

This is my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WebDriverSample()
{
    IWebDriver webDriver;
    //IWebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);
    //webDriver.Dispose();

    //webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);   
    //webDriver.Dispose();


    webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    webDriver.Dispose();
}
```

When using Firefox 47.0.2, I did not need to use `geckodriver` at all and it worked just fine.
Now, since browsers are getting updated, at some point I need to start using new versions. So, I need to find out what to do in order to be able to adapt to new changes and use `geckodriver`

Any suggestons?